# Change Font of a ListView Column

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to set a ListView item or a specific column in the ListView into bold. Here is my code but its not working so I am asking for help in order to make it work.

```
Do While dr.Read = True
    x = New ListViewItem(dr("ID").ToString)
    x.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
    x.SubItems.Add(dr("full_name"))
    x.SubItems(1).Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Arial"), 16, FontStyle.Bold)               
    x.SubItems.Add(dr("address"))
    x.SubItems.Add(dr("city"))

    ListView1.Items.Add(x)

Loop
```

Comment: There's no need to create a new `Font` object every time.  Create one before the loop and use it each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this code and it worked for me:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim item As New ListViewItem(i.ToString())

            item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False

            Dim subitem = item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString())

            subitem.Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Arial"), 16, FontStyle.Bold)

            item.SubItems.Add(i.ToString())

            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

There's something else up with your code.